# AWS SWF cancelling child workflows automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have AWS SWF workflow which creates many child workflows at runtime based on the number of input files. For x number of input files, it will create x number of child workflows. It works fine when number of input files is around 400 and successfully creates and executes 400 child workflows.

The issue is - when my input has around 500 files or more, **it starts that many child workflows successfully but then automatically cancels some of them**. I have tried different configurations but nothing worked.

I think AWS limit for number of child workflows is 1000, so that should not be issue.

Current child workflow config: 
Execution Start To Close Timeout:   2 hours 1 minute
Task Start To Close Timeout:    1 minute 30 seconds

Main workflow config:
Execution Start To Close Timeout:   9 hours
Task Start To Close Timeout:    1 minute 30 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that some exception is thrown in the workflow code which by default cancels workflows in the same cancellation scope. Read the [TryCatchFinally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/TryCatchFinally.html) documentation for more info about the cancellation semantic.

In general I wouldn't recommend that many child workflows in SWF, you can always do it hierarchically. Like 30 children, each of them 30 children give 900 workflows.